# Installing concmath on a mac

Tags: fonts, texlive, mactex, font-encodings

I've tried using `tlmgr` to install the `concmath` package, but I keep getting the following error:

```
! Font T1/ccr/m/n/10=eorm10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found
.<to be read again>
relax
```

what should I do to install it correctly? I've also tried installing `beton`, `concrete` and `ccfonts` using `tlmgr`, all to no avail. Installing the `concrete` package gave me bitmap (pixely) fonts though (only when I omit `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`).

I'm using this document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{concmath}

\begin{document}
test

\end{document}
```

NOTE: I also use `microtype`, which makes the need for the non-pixel version even more pressing. Microtype can't do expansion on these things..

Comment: Did you install the full MacTeX?  If so, things should just work. You *do* need the T1 encoding to get the Type1 versions of the fonts, so that's not surprising.  But on my system, your document works without any prior installation.  How did you invoke `tlmgr`?

Comment: Your example compiles fine for me. I'm using the latest available version of MacTeX (TeXlive 2010) with updates. Try using TeX Live Utility instead of tlmgr directly, you might find it easier.

Comment: I've installed MacTex, but note that I have used the BasicTex installation, which doesn't install ALL the packages. When I use one, I manually add it by invoking `tlmgr` from the command line (there is also no GUI app for TeX Live Manager).

Comment: I agree with Frédéric: even with BasicTeX you can still use the [TeXLive Utility GUI](http://code.google.com/p/mactlmgr/). It will cause you fewer problems, I think. Also "manually add it by invoking `tlmgr` isn't enough information.  Are you using `sudo tlmgr` or just `tlmgr` when you run from the command line?

Comment: I'm using `sudo tlmgr install concmath`. What would be the benefit of using the Utility? Isn't it just a click and point version of the command line tool? Or does it have some other advantages (depenency tracking maybe?)

Comment: This has come up in other questions: Unless computer memory is critical, you are probably better off with a full install. In particular, this will make it easier to use files from other sources. Another reason is that your document would now be compiling; there might be dependencies that aren't obvious to determine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the packages **ecc** (for the T1 encoded Concrete fonts) and **cm-super** (for the Type1 version necessary for microtype).

I agree with @Frédéric about the full install of MacTeX.

Comment: I've installed full mactex now.. Yet there is a bunch of unused material in it (why would I install `Bibleref` if I don't need it?). I liked the sparse install because it made my tex-tree a bit more see through.

Comment: installation of these package isn't enough either

Comment: @romeovs I've a complete and up-to-date MacTeX and your example compiles perfectly. What's the problem?

Comment: Noone seems to get I do not want to install Full MacTex. Althoug this might fix this particular problem it doesn't feel right. Perhaps I'm being oversensitive 'bout this, but I want to be aware of what's inside my tex tree and why it's there. I've installed `ecc`, `cm-super` and `concmath`, which should be enough right? Then why doesn't it work? Using the "full-install" blackbox doesn't fulfill my needs.

Comment: @romeovs What's in TeX Live has been checked by many people. It's hard to tell what you need; your example seems to require only ccfonts, concmath, ecc and cm-super. There may be a font map problem: what's the answer of `kpsewhich pdftex.map` (from the terminal)?

Comment: `kpsewhich pdftex.map` answers this: `/usr/local/texlive/2010basic/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map`

Comment: @romeovs In that file there should be some lines starting with ecc, for example `eccc0500 SFCC0500 "T1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <cm-super-t1.enc <sfcc0500.pfb`. If not you have to update manually with `updmap-sys`, adding all the map files in the directory `/usr/local/texlive/2010basic/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/cm-super`